# is this also vallid in css file <variable name="key" value="#576767">

Tags: css, blogger, cdata

I was reading my **blogger** HTML code
where I saw CSS variable in CDTA in index.html

```
<![CDATA[    
<Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#2196f3"  value="#2196f3"/>
    .page{
    backgroung-color: $(keycolor);
    }
]]>
```

well i know in css

```
    :root{
  --keycolor:#2196f3;
}
 .page{
        backgroung-color: var(--keycolor);
        }
```

this is how we do it but what is <variable/> here, can we use it in the CSS file
then how to use it

Answer (score 0):

`<Variable>` seems to be a way to define variables in Blogger Templates.

It is not a standard HTML tag, and is something used by Blogger only.

```
<Variable name="keycolor" description="Main Color" type="color" default="#2196f3"  value="#2196f3"/>
```

The attributes are pretty self explanatory - name, value etc.

`type` can be font, color etc.

They cannot be used anywhere except the Blogger template editor.

[Link](http://bguide.blogspot.com/2008/05/template-variables.html)